# BBC Embedded Media Player - "insufficient bandwidth to stream this programme"

Tags: javascript, android, bbc-glow

### Background

We are using Android [JustOp K10A](http://www.justop.com/catalog/audio-and-video/media-players-en/justop-k10a-quad-core-android-tv-box-mini-pc-dongle.html) HDMI sticks to display an MVC 4 Management Information dashboard website on 50 inch telly's around our company. In one section of this webpage we are using the [BBC Embedded Media Player](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/help/7277283.stm) (EMP), which looks great, and works beautifully on the Dolphin browser (which supports Flash and can display in fullscreen). The Android stick is connected via WiFi (the hub is very close to the telly, so the signal is strong), which in turn connects to our uncontended 20 mbps synchronous EFM line, so a very fat pipe indeed.

The code is all Javascript.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        reload("bbc_one_london", "BBC One");
    });

    function updateEmp(widthEmp, heightEmp) {
        width = widthEmp;
        height = heightEmp;
        $('bbc_emp_embed_emp1').morph({ width: widthEmp + 'px', height: heightEmp + 'px'    });
    }

    function reload(url, title) {
        var emp = new embeddedMedia.Player();
        emp.setWidth("100%");
        emp.setHeight("100%");
        emp.setDomId("emp1");
        emp.quality = "low";
        emp.set("config_settings_autoPlay", "true");
        emp.setPlaylist('http://www.bbc.co.uk/emp/simulcast/bbc_news24.xml');
        emp.setConfig('http://www.bbc.co.uk/emp/simulcast/config_bbc_news24.xml');
        emp.write();
    }

</script>
```

### The problem

After one to four hours of display, the feed stops and displays "Insufficient Bandwidth to Stream this Programme". The only way to kick off the BBC feed is to refresh the whole page.

### The question

There is little or no information about the EMP in the public domain, I can find no documentation or enumerations of methods and properties the EMP object has that may help me mitigate this problem.

- Is there a property I can use that will either restart the stream on fail or drop its quality to a point it will not drop out?
- Is there an event I can hang a restart off of on the EMP object?
- Refreshing the object once an hour sounds like a fudge, but it might work, so I am considering that as a last resort.